"Numerus parte altera longior"
In "The Origin of Mathematical Induction" (1917) by W.H. Bussey, p. 201, I learned that the mathematician Maurolycus in 1575 defined the term numerus parte altera longior to mean n(n – 1).
Can you explain the grammar of this phrase, specifically how it means what it is supposed to mean? I would have thought that it meant "a number greater than another part" or perhaps "a number greater by another part". What suggests multiplication? What suggests adding 1?

Have you found a copy of the original text by Maurocylus? What he calls other numbers might give insight into reading this name. (Also, isn't it n(n-1)?)

@JoonasIlmavirta I haven't found the original text yet, but the title is Arithmeticorum duo libri. And yes, it's n(n–1). I'll correct it right now.

@IlyaDaskevics Euge! Vestigium! Praeterea in capitulo XXVIIº Boëthium e philosophia Pythagorae delectum 'altera' vocabuli illuminare video. Visne ex hoc responsum conficere?

This might change with more information, but my initial reading is that the number is to be thought of as an area.
The figure in question is a rectangle that is longer in one direction than the other, or parte altera longior.
As we are speaking of integers as building blocks, the expected offset is one.
The same name could stand for other things, like n(n+1) or ½n(n-1), depending the preferred indexing and whether one thinks of rectangles or triangles.
The name is sensible, but does not uniquely point to the formula.
This is true more often than not in modern mathematics as well.

Is it common to say numerus for an area, rather than, say, area, regio, or rectangulus?

@BenKovitz I don't know. I think it's fairer to say that this is a "number arising from an area" rather than "number" being used to mean "area". Maybe the modern concept of "triangular number" is a good comparison: it is a number and it has a geometric interpretation, but we call it just a number anyway.
